# При загрузке модели keras ошибка AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Язык: python
Фреймворк: tensorflow/keras

При попытке загрузить ранее обученную и сохраненную модель, возникает вот такая ошибка:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-aa7422fa3072> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/test111_stand')

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/saving/legacy/serialization.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    533             obj = object_registration._GLOBAL_CUSTOM_OBJECTS[object_name]
    534         else:
--> 535             obj = module_objects.get(object_name)
    536             if obj is None:
    537                 raise ValueError(

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Архитектура модели:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Input(shape=(1), dtype=tf.string),
    vectorize_layer,
    keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=177475, output_dim=18, input_length=max_word),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')])
```

Определение vectorize_layer:

```
vectorize_layer = keras.layers.TextVectorization(
    standardize=standartize_str,
    max_tokens=177474,
    split="character",
    output_mode='int',
    output_sequence_length=max_word)

vectorize_layer.adapt(df['data'])
```

Определение пользовательской функции для стандартизации:

```
def standartize_str(s):
  s = tf.strings.regex_replace(s, " ","")
  s = tf.strings.lower(s)
  return s
```

Насколько я понял, проблема в использовании пользовательской функции стандартизации standartize_str. Судя по всему при сохранении модели она не серилизуется. Если обойтись без этой функции и воспользоваться стандартной функцией стандартизации, которую предоставляет слой TextVectorization, то ранее сохраненная модель загружается корректно.

Я пробовал добавлять декоратор, к функции стандартизации, но это не помогло:

```
@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable(package='custom_package', name='standartize_str')
def standartize_str(s):
  s = tf.strings.regex_replace(s, " ","")
  s = tf.strings.lower(s)
  return s
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как корректно применять пользовательскую функцию стандартизации в слое векторизации TextVectorization, чтобы после сохранения модели, в дальнейшем модель загружалась без ошибок?